# How to override a linked scene in Blender?

Tags: linked-data, scene, viewlayers, library-overrides

I am experienced with Maya but new to Blender, after long digging I still can't find an answer, can you help me out?

My question is: how to override a linked scene in Blender?

Create 2 empty files, link scene one to another.

As you can see, it says Shift + Click will create override, but it does nothing actually...

[image]

I found that a few people have asked the same question as me, but have not received answers yet.

https://blenderartists.org/t/override-a-linked-scene/1350794

Thank you very much for your help.

---

If overriding a scene is not currently feasible method, can you share a way how to link view layer?

Comment: where did you see this tooltip? i tried hovering over alot of things in this area as shown in your picture but i can't see this tooltip anywhere. im using blender 3.1. you?

Comment: hover to the anchor icon on scene selection, the one beside "X" delete scene icon.

Comment: i dont have the anchor icon. only the copy and x icon. is it always displayed or how do i get this icon to show?

Comment: when you link a file, select a scene instead of collection, object and etc.

Comment: yeah nothing happens when i SHIFT + click. what exactly do you need to link? can you not just link the objects you need? coz there is also a menu under: Object -> Relations -> Make Library Override.

Comment: I need the view layers. not creating another fresh scene

Answer (score 1):

Shift+Click still not working in Blender 3.3. You can override a linked scene by using the outliner by the following steps:

1. Select Outliner Display Mode: Scenes
2. Right click the linked Scene -> Library Override -> Make -> Selected/Content/Selected & Content depends on your needs

[image]

Answer (score -1):

looks like this feature is not implemented yet.